# Script Causing Page to Reload Infinitely

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a simple script with next/previous buttons that cycle through an array of pages and I'm trying to get a "img" and "a" tag to not display on a certain page. For some reason the following line of code is causing the page to reload infinitely.

Faulty Code:

```
function buttonCheck() {
if ( window.location = "homefeed.php" )  document.getElementById('prev').style.display = "none";    
}
window.onload = buttonCheck;
```

Heres my full code:

```
<!-- NEXT PAGE SCRIPT -->
    <script>
    var pageList = ["homefeed.php", "allfeed.php", "usfeed.php"];
    var url = window.location.pathname; // e.g. http://me.com/index.html
    var page = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1); // e.g. index.html
    var currentPosition = pageList.indexOf(page); // e.g. 0, 1 or 2 

        // NEXT BUTTON
   function next(){
    if(currentPosition<pageList.length-1) {window.location = pageList[++currentPosition];
    }
    else {window.location = pageList[0];
    }
  }
        //PREVIOUS BUTTON
    function previous() {
     window.location = pageList[currentPosition - 1];}
    //HOMEFEED DISPLAY NO BUTTON
    function buttonCheck() {
     if ( window.location = "homefeed.php" )  document.getElementById('prev').style.display = "none";   
    }
    window.onload = buttonCheck;
 </script>
         <!-- NEXT PAGE SCRIPT -->
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. FYI: I have tried just the (If) line on its own without the Window.Onload function, and still i have the same results. When i remove just the following line, the problem goes away. 
The problem seems to be with this line in particular:

```
if ( window.location = "homefeed.php" )  document.getElementById('prev').style.display = "none";
```

**UPDATE:** 
**I have fixed the infinite reloading problem but the display style is now not working. Here is my updated code:**

```
    //HOMEFEED DISPLAY NO BUTTON
if ( window.location == "homefeed.php" )  document.getElementById('prev').style.display = "none";
```

**UPDATE:
I have fixed the display style error by narrowing it down to the Window.Location. Updated code below:**

```
var lastPart = window.location.href.split("/").pop();
    //HOMEFEED DISPLAY NO BUTTON
if ( lastPart == "homefeed.php" )   { document.getElementById('prev').style.display = "none"
```

Comment: In `window.location = "homefeed.php"` - you're using an assignment operator `=` which should be a comparison `==`

Comment: Another question which is a good example why code editors with syntax highlighting do make so much sense…

Comment: Thanks, That stopped the infinite reloading problem. But now the display style is not changing to none. I have removed the window onload functions as well because they were only a step i took to get the infinite loading to stop. Will post my updated code above.

Comment: @feeela Im using Dreamweaver CS6 with syntax highlighting, honestly that was just a noob mistake on my part.

Comment: _“But now the display style is not changing to none.”_ - well then most likely `window.location` does not contain what you thought it does to begin with, so log it to console and _verify_. (And after that, go read up on what sub-properties the location object provides.)

Comment: `console.log( window.location )` and see what is in there

Comment: As the guys said above, console log within the if.. Make sure you also have specified an id="prev" on your html element. Perhaps you used class? I would console log inside the if statement first to ensure your getting in as you may not be matching the window location correctly?

Comment: Thanks guys, much appreciated. +9000 Rep, Ive solved the problem with the display style by narrowing it down to the Window.Location problem.

Comment: What i ended up needing to do was do a window.location.href.split to get the last segment of the URL and that seemed to fix all issues. Updated code above ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem:

```
if ( window.location = "homefeed.php" )  {
    document.getElementById('prev').style.display = "none";    
}
```

You are **asigning** instead of comparing. You should do:

```
window.location == "homefeed.php"
```

However, I'd use `location.pathname`, as `location` is not really a string and contains the absolute URL:

```
window.location.pathname === "/homefield.php"
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Although the display style is now not changing to none on load. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, maybe the comparison is not exactly what you need. When you are in the page you want to be, check `location.pathname` in the browser's console to see what the actual value is, and use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( window.location.href == "homefeed.php" )  document.getElementById('prev').style.display = "none";
```

You had missed out on '==' and '.href'

So always check your syntax before asking questions, most of the times these lead to errors. I also once did a syntactical error in my code and asked a question.

Also, window.location's href property returns the path, so if you wanted to compare the path, you should have added window.location.href also.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple error :)

You are trying to check whether the page is homefeed.php...Carefully notice the code ...

Notice the equal sign there... Did something strike? If not, read further.

You are equating window.location to homefeed.php that is what keep setting your window.location to homefeed.php

All you need to do is this

```
if ( window.location == "homefeed.php" )  document.getElementById('prev').style.display = "none";
```

Cheers!